# Change size of viewing area after changing size of UINavigationBar and UITabBar

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5, uinavigationbar, uitabbar

I'm currently working on my very first app and I've changed the size of the UINavigationBar and UITabBar and now I have extra space black space in the general viewing area (etc. ViewController, DetailViewController). How can I change the viewing area to accommodate for this new size?

I've pasted how I'm currently setting the new size for both UINavigationBar and the UITabBar.

```
/* Get the screenarea of the device */
CGRect screenArea = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];

/* Define the size of the navigation bar */
CGRect viewHeaderbBarFrame = navigationBar.frame;
viewHeaderbBarFrame.origin.y = screenArea.origin.y;
viewHeaderbBarFrame.origin.x = screenArea.origin.x;
viewHeaderbBarFrame.size.height = 44;
viewHeaderbBarFrame.size.width = screenArea.size.width;
navigationBar.frame = viewHeaderbBarFrame;

/* Define the size of the footer bar */
CGRect viewTabBarFrame = tabBar.frame;
viewTabBarFrame.origin.y = screenArea.size.height - 26;
viewTabBarFrame.origin.x = screenArea.origin.x;
viewTabBarFrame.size.height = 46;
viewTabBarFrame.size.width = screenArea.size.width;
tabBar.frame = viewTabBarFrame;
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

basically by shrinking your tabbar and navbar, you need your view to expand. I'm assuming that you are using a tabbar for primary navigation.

Figure out the proper size and adjust your view like this:

```
[[self.tabBarController.view.subviews objectAtIndex:0] setFrame:CGRectMake(newX,newY,newWidth,newHeight)];
```

in the buyer beware category, if your goal is the app store, you would be wise to review the guidelines on modifying those elements.  I'm not sure of all the specific points, but I think apple frowns making changes like that to plainly displayed core navigation elements.

Also, this approach works well for the current screen dimensions, but may not work if the rumors are true and the next phone has a bigger screen.

be well.

Answer (score 1):

You should never have to mess with the view height in this way. Views are pushed onto the nav bar. Their size should be set to fit a 320 x 480 screen minus tab, nav, and title bars. And you should set the AutoResize width/height as flexible and the left/rigth/top/bottom to not-flexible (just leave them out).

> view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight

iOS likes everything to to be spring loaded and pinned to one another. Then when you rotate things, it all sticks and moves properly. They do all the work for you. So, it's best to embrace their funky way of handing things. The interface builder gui can help. It even lets you test out rotation if you want. And you can set the option of tab/nav/title bars too. Or if you understand it, then you can also do this manually.